# Image border in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to have an animated border over an `Image`. But to my surprise, only `Rectangle` is able to provide `border`. I want to have a dotted line moving round the `Image`. How to get such animation. This is my sample code which just provide a border to the `Image`.

```
Rectangle {
    width: image.width + 5
    height: image.height + 5
    border.color: "yellow"
    border.width: 5
    color: "transparent"

    Image {
        id: image
        anchor.centerIn: parent
        source: ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `Rectangle.border` doesn't allow you to do that. As a workaround you can use `Canvas` instead.

Comment: I've never used a `Canvas` before. Can you provide me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Because Canvas element in QML does not have the setLineDash() method as JavaScript canvas has (but you can still emulate it, see [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/56628/qml-canvas-dashed-dotted-lines/2)), the easiest way (imho) is to use BorderImage with a custom image with dotted pattern. Please see example how to use BorderImage [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-imageelements-borderimage-qml.html).

Also you can write your own QML element derived from QQuickPaintedItem or QQuickItem in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Take [BorderImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-borderimage.html) instead of [Rectangle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html):

```
 Image {
   BorderImage { 
   }    
 }
```